# Problems when installing goose

Tags: python, anaconda, goose

I followed the exact instructions from https://github.com/grangier/python-goose when installing goose, and after I typed in "mkvirtualenv --no-site-packages goose", this is what I got:

```
172-27-220-167:~ yitongwang$ mkvirtualenv --no-site-packages goose
New python executable in goose/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip...done.
Error: deactivate must be sourced. Run 'source deactivate'
instead of 'deactivate'.
Usage: source deactivate
removes the 'bin' directory of the environment activated with 'source
activate' from PATH. 
(goose)172-27-220-167:~ yitongwang$
```

I have installed virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper using 'sudo pip install virtualenv/virtualenvwrapper', and the weirdest thing is I seemed to still manage to enter the goose virtual environment (seems like it). After cloning into the git repo and change to the directory python-goose cloned earlier, I attempted to run 'pip install -r requirements.txt' and 'python setup.py install', and these are the errors:

```
In file included from _imagingft.c:31:

/Users/yitongwang/anaconda/include/ft2build.h:56:10: fatal error: 'freetype/config/ftheader.h' file not found

#include <freetype/config/ftheader.h>

         ^

1 error generated.

Building using 4 processes

gcc -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -L/Users/yitongwang/anaconda/lib -arch x86_64 -arch x86_64 build/temp.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/_imagingft.o -L/Users/yitongwang/.virtualenvs/goose/lib -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/Cellar/freetype/2.5.5/lib -L/usr/lib -L/Users/yitongwang/anaconda/lib -lfreetype -o build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/PIL/_imagingft.so

clang: error: no such file or directory: 'build/temp.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/_imagingft.o'

error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Command "/Users/yitongwang/.virtualenvs/goose/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/64/dhzf31k50zg22rbgbz79c3dw0000gn/T/pip-build-nL0d0r/Pillow/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/64/dhzf31k50zg22rbgbz79c3dw0000gn/T/pip-k7HUgC-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/yitongwang/.virtualenvs/goose/include/site/python2.7" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/64/dhzf31k50zg22rbgbz79c3dw0000gn/T/pip-build-nL0d0r/Pillow

    In file included from _imagingft.c:31:
/Users/yitongwang/anaconda/include/ft2build.h:56:10: fatal error: 
      'freetype/config/ftheader.h' file not found
#include <freetype/config/ftheader.h>
         ^
1 error generated.
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'build/temp.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/_imagingft.o'
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

I'm not sure particularly what's wrong, cause I have tried a few times from scratch where I deleted the directory 'python-goose' and './virtualenv' as well as the path from .bash_profile.

Any help would be much much appreciated!

Thanks

P.S. I'm using Anaconda with Python 2.7 in it.

Answer (score 0):

[Take a look at this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19869059/why-i-am-suddenly-seeing-usage-source-deactivate-whenever-i-run-virtualenvwra).Here also the same problem is highlighted.It is related to workon which is in /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh and calls deactivate but a script in anaconda bin directory also does the same stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using virtualenv, try creating an environment with conda (`conda create`) and install all the goose dependencies into it (apparently freetype is one of them). Then install goose directly into that environment. Something like `conda create -n goose freetype ...` (replace `...` with the [other dependencies](https://github.com/grangier/python-goose/blob/develop/requirements.txt) of goose), `source activate goose`, `python setup.py install` (from the goose directory).

Answer (score 0):

from your command prompt write pip install goose-extractor