# deactivate conflict in virtualenvwapper and anaconda

Tags: python, virtualenv, anaconda, virtualenvwrapper

I'm using virtualenv to switch my python dev env. But when I run `workon my_env`, I meet such error message:

```
Error: deactivate must be sourced. Run 'source deactivate'
instead of 'deactivate'.

Usage: source deactivate

removes the 'bin' directory of the environment activated with 'source
activate' from PATH.
```

After some searches on google, it seems that `workon`, which is defined in /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh, calls `deactivate`. And there is a script with the same name is present in Anaconda's bin, so it gets called by workon by mistake.

Any suggestion for working around this conflict?

Answer (score 15):

One solution which works for me is to rename `deactivate` in Anaconda's bin:

`mv deactivate conda-deactivate`

Comment: I picked the same name before seeing this answer. +1 for `conda-deactivate` as new standard!

Comment: This is fragile since conda is also using deactivate in several places.

Answer (score 10):

I agree with the comment by @FredrikHedman that renaming scripts in the anaconda/miniconda `bin` directory has the potential to be fragile. His full post led me to what I feel is a more robust answer. (Thanks!)

Rather than simply throwing away any errors thrown by calling `deactivate`, we could simply condition that call on whether the *function* would be called versus the *file*. As mentioned, virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper create a function named `deactivate`; the *condas call a script file of the same name.

So, in the `virtualenvwrapper.sh` script, we can change the following two lines which test for whether `deactivate` is merely callable:

```
type deactivate >/dev/null 2>&1
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
```

with the stricter test for whether it's a shell function:

```
if [ -n $ZSH_VERSION ] ; then
    nametype="$(type -w deactivate)"
else
    nametype="$(type -t deactivate)"
fi
if [ "${nametype##* }" == "function" ]
```

This change avoids triggering the spurious error noted in the original question, but doesn't risk redirecting other useful errors or output into silent oblivion.

Note the variable substitution on `nametype` in the comparison. This is because the output of `type -w` under `zsh` returns something like "`name: type`" as opposed to `type -t` under `bash` which returns simply "`type`". The substitution deletes everything up to the last space character, if any spaces exist, leaving only the type value. This harmlessly does nothing in `bash`.

(Thanks to @toprak for the `zsh` test and for the correct flag, `type -w`, under zsh. I look forward to more cross-shell coding tips!)

As ever, I appreciate constructive feedback and comments!

Comment: it works, this solution has my vote I agree that conda could be using deactivate in another ways an changes its name not sound great idea, let the conda alone !!

Comment: `type -t` doesn't work in zsh (5.1.1). Updating `python -mpip install -U virtualenvwrapper` fixed the conflict with pyenv's deactivate for me.

Comment: I get instead the error `-bash: type: -w: invalid option`, so I had to go back to version before of the edition, i.e. I don't have an `else`, and instead of  `nametype="$(type -w deactivate)"` I have `nametype="$(type -t deactivate)"`

Answer (score 3):

You can edit /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh to make `deactivate` point to an absolute path to whatever `deactivate` it is supposed to be referencing.

Comment: Where is the right deactivate? I used brew to install my virtualenvwrapper. And there are so many "deactivate"s in /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh. Any elegant solution to change the deactivate it use?

Comment: virtualenvwrapper expects deactivate to be a shell function, there is no path to point to.

Answer (score 2):

As I do not have enough reputations to add a comment:
**Thomas Capote's** suggestion is fine (thx 4 that), except **"zsh" does not have a "-t" option for** the build-in command **"type"**. Therefore its necessary to add another conditional statement to get desired result for "nametype":

```
# Anaconda workaround for "source deactivate" message:
# Start of workaround:
#type deactivate >/dev/null 2>&1
#if [ $? -eq 0 ]
if [ -n $ZSH_VERSION ] ; then
    nametype="$(type -w deactivate)"
else
    nametype="$(type -t deactivate)"
fi
if [ "${nametype##* }" == "function" ]
# End of workaround
```

Hope it helps other zsh users.

Comment: Thank you so much, @toprak, for the helpful addition regarding zsh! i will edit my answer to incorporate this and credit you.

Answer (score 1):

In anaconda `activate` is an executable script located in the anaconda `bin` directory, but is a function in in `virtualenvwrapper.sh`.  So this is sort of a namespace collision problem, but also a case of overlap in functionality.

Anacondas is a python distribution and – among many other things – has support for dealing with virtual environment via `conda env` while the virtualenvwrapper is focused on working with different virtual environments.  Just renaming the anaconda/bin/activate script is a brittle solution and may break `conda`.

The code of `virtualenvwrapper.sh` (function `workon`) executes `deactivate` which happens to use the anaconda script.  This script returns an error.  The `workon` code then goes on and removes the `deactivate` name and sources its own `deactivate` and also creates a `deactivate` function on the fly.

In summary, it does the right thing and the "error" can be viewed more as a warning.  If you want to make it go away you can modify the workon function (search for the line `# Deactivate any current environment "destructively"`)

```
deactivate
-->
deactivate >/dev/null 2>&1
```

(I have suggested this change to the virtualenvwrapper maintainer)