# Python source deactivate has no effect

Tags: python, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I am attempting to deactivate my Python virtual environment. However, running `source deactivate` appears to have no effect:

```
(general) machine:~ user$ source deactivate 
pyenv-virtualenv: deactivate 3.6.0/envs/general
(general) machine:~ user$
```

Even after running the `source deactivate` command, I still appear to be in the `general` virtual environment. I also tried running just `deactivate`, but received the following message:

```
pyenv-virtualenv: deactivate must be sourced. Run 'source deactivate' instead of 'deactivate'
```

If it's relevant, I'm running macOS Sierra 10.12.4.

Comment: Don't `source`, just `deactivate`

Comment: `source bin activate` to activate, and `deactivate` to deactivate.

Comment: I did just run `deactivate` though, and it mentioned that I had to run `source deactivate`, so that doesn't appear to do the trick.

Comment: any chance you are using anaconda?

Comment: Which command did you use to *create* the virtual machine?

Comment: @LesterT. how would I verify that if I were?

Comment: @chepner I can't say I recall exactly what I did, although I want to say I followed instructions found here: http://python-guide-pt-br.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/

Comment: @VincentRusso try `anaconda -V` . I'm asking because there seems to be a naming conflict with anaconda and virtualenvwrapper that gives rise to your problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30308190/deactivate-conflict-in-virtualenvwapper-and-anaconda

Comment: @LesterT. Does not appear as if I am using anaconda, as running `anaconda -V` yields `-bash: anaconda: command not found`.

Comment: Have you solved this problem?