# I want my already created virtualenv to have access to system packages

Tags: python, opencv, virtualenv

I've recently installed opencv3 on ubuntu 14.04. The tutorial I followed was for some reason using a virtualenv. Now I want to move opencv from the virtual to my global environment. The reason for this is that I can't seem to use the packages that are installed on my global environment which is getting on my nerves. So how can I do that?

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure I got your question right, but **probably** your virtualenv has been created without specifying the option `--system-site-packages`, which gives your virtualenv access to the packages you installed system-wise.

If you run `virtualenv --system-site-packages tutorial_venv` instead of just `virtualenv tutorial_venv` when creating your tutorial virtualenv, you might be fine.

Fyi, using a virtualenv with only local dependencies it's a fairly widespread practice, which:

- gives you isolation and reproducibility in production scenarios
- makes possible for users without the privilege of installing packages system-wide to run and develop a python application

The last benefit might be the reason why your tutorial suggested a virtualenv based approach.

Comment: that makes sense somewhat. now when i run virtualenv --system-site-packages cv (cv is the name of virtualenv), i create a new folder named cv in my current working directory and cv still does not have access to my system packages. What do i do now? .. Sorry if I'm being super noob about this

Comment: Did you remember to activate the virtualenv? (`source cv/bin/activate`) How do you know it doesn't have access to them? Could you be more precise?

Comment: here's what i do.   workon cv.(i get a message that starts with 'Usage: source deactivate') --> source activate --> python --> import skimage --> no module named skimage

Comment: Ah, so you're using virtualenvwrapper, you may want to specify that on your question. And to update with the error message you got. Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with virtualenvwrapper. I quickly found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19869059/why-i-am-suddenly-seeing-usage-source-deactivate-whenever-i-run-virtualenvwra but I am not sure it is related.